# View doesn't display data from a model

Tags: qt

could someone please tell me, why this code for the freaking hell, doesn't display data in a view?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

class File_Model : public QAbstractItemModel
{
private:
    QStringList data_;
public:

    File_Model()
    {}
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {


        return data_.at(index.row());
    }

    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch(role)
        {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        data_ =  value.toStringList();
        emit dataChanged(index,index);
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex&) const
    {
        return createIndex(row,column);
    }
    virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex&) const
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex&) const
    {
        return data_.size();
    }
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex&) const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QDir dir(QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::HomeLocation));
    File_Model* model = new File_Model;//(dir.entryList());
   bool t =  model->setData(QModelIndex(),dir.entryList());
    QListView* view = new QListView;
    view->setModel(model);

    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I replaced your custom model with a `QStringListModel` and it worked fine. So, there's a problem with your `File_Model` class. Now it's a simple matter of finding what's wrong with the class :P

Comment: @ChrisParton yes, as webcletic rightly pointed this out to me, Qt::DisplayRole needed to be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on your `data` function. You should check the role before displaying something:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant(data_.at(index.row()));

    return QVariant();
}
```

Also note that you don't have to use the `setData` in your case. `setData` is udes for editing models, not initializing them with some values.

> To enable editing in your model, you must also implement setData(),
>   and reimplement flags() to ensure that ItemIsEditable is returned.

Instead you could add a public function in your model and call it instead:

```
void setEntries(QStringList entries)
{
    beginInsertRows(createIndex(0,0), 0, entries.count());
    data_ =  entries;
    endInsertRows();
}
```

Comment: @webcletic, thanks so much, I thought I was going demented. about this setData, do I understand it correctly that setData is called by a view into this model is attached?

Comment: setData is called when the user edits the model manually from the view. Eg double click on a cell and change its value.